# Multiplying values using javascript, results shown in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, here is what i'm trying to do.

I have a dropdown list, which shows how many different fruits is a fruit worth.
I want to add a input box before the Dropdown, where you can input a numeric value.
After inputting for example 5, and selecting Apples from dropdown form, I want the result to be 10 bananas and 15 oranges.

How to achieve this?

Here it is live:

http://jsfiddle.net/2A5Xx/1/

JS:
        $(document).ready(function () {

```
        function showTab( name ) 
        {
            name = '#' + name;

            $('div').not(name).hide();

            $(name).show();
        }

        $('#dropdown').change( function() {

            showTab( $( this ).val() );
        });

        showTab( $('#dropdown').val() );

    });
```

HTML:

```
<form>
              <p>I want to sell
                  <input type="text" value="Input number" maxlength="5">
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
            <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select a fruit</option>
            <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
            <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
            <option value="Pineapple">Pineapple</option>
            <option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
<div id="Apple">
    <ul>
        <li>2 bananas</li>
        <li>3 oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Banana">
    <ul>
        <li>2 apples</li>
        <li>4 oranges</li>
    </ul>'</div>
<div id="Orange">
    <ul>
        <li>1 pineapple</li>
        <li>5 watermelons</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Pineapple">
    <ul>
        <li>2 oranges</li>
        <li>3 bananas</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="Watermelon">
    <ul>
        <li>2 pineapples</li>
        <li>1 banana</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to amend your HTML so that you have an element to place the quantities, along with their default unit:

```
<div id="Apple">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-val="2"></span> bananas</li>
        <li><span data-val="3"></span> oranges</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then in your JS, you need to grab that number and multiply it by the entered value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showTab(name) {
        $('div').hide();
        var $div = $('#' + name).show();
        var number = parseInt($('.number').val(), 0);
        $('span', $div).each(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).data('val') * number);
        });
    }

    $('#dropdown').change(function () {
        showTab($(this).val());
    });

    showTab($('#dropdown').val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2A5Xx/3/)

Comment: Sir, you are a hero!
Thank you!